# Unable to scale Chrome on Hdpi screen for Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, chrome

I have a MBPR 13 running Arch Linux with only xorg and xmonad. However im not able to scale Chrome for Hdpi instead everything is super tiny.

What I have tried so far is the reccomendations on Arch Wiki but id does not work:

```
google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=12
```

What do I need to do for Chrome to work on my Hdpi screen?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a factor 2 instead of 12:

```
chromium --force-device-scale-factor=2
```

And since you run xmonad you might also try calculating and setting your DPI in .Xresources like shown here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#X_Resources

(wiki states that Chromium is using dpi from X server https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#X_Server)